# React - filter nested array and update the state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, filter, state

1. I have a state with an array of objects. Objects represent workers. Each worker has a name property and a nested object (projects2021). Inside the nested object there's **an array of objects** (projectsList):

   ```
       [{
        name: 'John',
        projects2021: {
            hours: 15,
            projectsAll: 10,
            projectsNames: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
            projectsList: [

                {
                    month: 'january',
                    projectName: 'germany',
                    status: 'vodja',
                    hours: 50,
                },
                {
                    month: 'february',
                    projectName: 'germany',
                    status: 'vodja',
                    hours: 50,
                },


            ],
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'David',
        projects2021: {
            hours: 15,
            projectsAll: 10,
            projectsNames: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
            projectsList: [
                {
                    month: 'january',
                    projectName: 'germany',
                    status: 'vodja',
                    hours: 50,
                },
                {
                    month: 'february',
                    projectName: 'germany',
                    status: 'vodja',
                    hours: 50,
                },


            ],
        },
    }
   ```

   ]

const [workers, setWorkers] = useState(users);

2. I would like to map over the state and render the workers in a way where only the projects with a given month would be shown. For example, if I clicked "january", I would like react to display **all the workers (their names)**, but **only** the projects with a **"month" property of "january"**. In layman's terms: filtering the table by a given month. This is what I've done so far:

   ```
    const filterByMonth = (month) => {
    let mainArray = [];
    workers.map((worker) => {
        const result = worker.projects2021.projectsList.filter(
            (data) => data.month === month
        );
        mainArray.push(result)

    });
    setWorkers(mainArray);
   ```

   };
3. With my approach I mutate the state directly (which is not ok) and thus loose certain parts of an object. I want to retain my object and only change the state of a nested array of objects (projectsList).
4. I was thinking of a way where I would spread the object first and then concat/push the nested array inside of an object.

I do apologize if my question isn't structured the way it should be, but this is my first time posting and I am a self-taught fella :).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread to achieve it. Here's a sample:

```
const filterByMonth = (month) => {
   const result = workers.map((worker) => {
       return {...worker , projects2021: worker.projects2021.projectsList.filter(data => data.month === month)}
   });
   setWorkers(result);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of accomplishing this is to have workers as constant and filtered workers as state.

```
const workers= [{
 name: 'John',
 projects2021: {
     hours: 15,
     projectsAll: 10,
     projectsNames: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
     projectsList: [
         {
             month: 'january',
             projectName: 'germany',
             status: 'vodja',
             hours: 50,
         },
     ],
 },
 {...}]
const [filteredWorkers, setFilteredWorkers]=useState(workers)
```

Then apply filtering to the state

```
const filterByMonth = (month) => {
 let newWorkers = workers.filter((worker)=> worker.projects2021.projectsList.month === month);

 setFilteredWorkers(newWorkers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can use this code:

```js
const workers = [{
     name: 'John',
     projects2021: {
         hours: 15,
         projectsAll: 10,
         projectsNames: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
         projectsList: [
             {
                 month: 'january',
                 projectName: 'germany',
                 status: 'vodja',
                 hours: 50,
             },
             {
                 month: 'february',
                 projectName: 'germany',
                 status: 'vodja',
                 hours: 50,
             },
         ],
     },
 },
 {
     name: 'David',
     projects2021: {
         hours: 15,
         projectsAll: 10,
         projectsNames: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
         projectsList: [
             {
                 month: 'january',
                 projectName: 'germany',
                 status: 'vodja',
                 hours: 50
             },
             {
                 month: 'february',
                 projectName: 'germany',
                 status: 'vodja',
                 hours: 50
             },
         ],
     },
 }];

const updatedWorkers = workers.map(worker => {
        const updatedProjectsList = worker.projects2021.projectsList.filter(item =>
          item.month === 'january'
        );
        return ({...worker, projects2021:{...worker.projects2021, projectsList: updatedProjectsList}});
    });

console.log(updatedWorkers)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).